# Convert bug fixes (r215031, etc) to Clang releases (3.6, 4.0, etc)

Tags: clang, llvm, release

I'm trying to work through an issue with LLVM and Clang's integrated assembler. From [Bug 18916 don't err on ".att_syntax prefix"](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=18916#c2), Comment 2:

> I'd say this is fixed by r215031.

I've tested on a number of Clang's, and we are still experiencing the problem. We even build Clang from sources on occasion using the [LLVM Release](http://llvm.org/releases) bits.

How do I map a R number to a Clang release? Or determine which release first enjoyed the fix provided by the R number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can check the source code repository and see which revision was when llvm / clang was branched for a release. Also, there are some backports of the revisions from the mainline to the release branch.

In particular, the coming 3.7 release was branched from r242221 (see e.g. http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/llvm/branches/release_37/) and 3.6 was based on r225991

Therefore I believe that r215031 should be in 3.6 release.

PS: Note that clang 4.0 does not exist.

Comment: Oh, those are SVN revision numbers. I've never seen SVN revision numbers that high before. But thanks for all of it because I still would have to look it up.

Comment: LLVM's commit pace is about 25k commits per year and the project is more than 10 years old, so... :)